# OpenGL ES 2.0 - How to batch draw particles that have unique translations, rotations, scales, and alphas?

Tags: shaders, opengl-es, opengl-es2, particles, vertex-arrays

I've combined all of my vertex data for many particles into a single array.  How would I batch draw all of those particles in a manner that preserves their unique translations?

Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084334/opengl-es-2-0-how-to-batch-draw-particles-that-have-unique-translations-rotat

Answer (score 2):

> I've combined all of my vertex data for many particles into a single array.

How did you do this exactly? Details?

You could "secretly contain" the transformation matrix for each particle's vertex in 4 texture coordinates.

So, you'd have a vertex format like:

```
vec4 position
vec4 color
vec4 matTexcoord0
vec4 matTexcoord1
vec4 matTexcoord2
vec4 matTexcoord3
vec4 texturingTexcoord
```

Little does the shader know that `matTexcoord0-matTexcoord3` are not actually texture coordinates.  No.  They are a *transformation matrix in disguise*.

Da da da dah!!

Effectively a `mat4x4` is passed using 4 `vec4`'s. So you apply the transformation matrix contained in `matTexcoord0-3` in the shader as a kind of `world` transform.  If you use [point sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497068/textured-points-in-opengl-es-2-0) this can be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the translation in your vertex shader. You must either have a parallel array which contains the translations for each vertex, or store the translations in a texture which you lookup in using some attribute of each particle.

(Note: Answering as if for WebGL; I have no actual GL ES experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Each particle needs it's own transformation matrix, so a parallel array or third element to the array of a unique tranform matrix is needed. Then before you draw a particle, multiply the current Modelview matrix by the particle's transform matrix.